# asp.net: Read data from uploaded Excel document

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, file-upload

I would like to know the best way to read data from an uploaded excel document. Im currently using http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/, which works good. The problem is that it cant read the values from checkboxes or radiobuttons. Im using asp.net framework 3.5. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have Excel installed on your system, you could include `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly and use that to do everything you need.